# Changing allotted values on parameters based on previously selected values on the parameters CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am making a CloudFormation template. I have a situation in which I want to change the parameters allotted values dynamically based on previously selected parameter values.

For example:

If parameter1 allotted values are True and False

parameter2 allotted values are 1,2,3, and 4.

If parameter1 is chosen True then parameter2 allotted values are 1,2,3, and 4 but if parameter1 is chosen False then parameter2 allotted values are 1 and 2.

I want a solution where the allotted values change automatically when the parameter1 is chosen False.

How to do this in CloudFormation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not possible. CloudFormation parameters are static and you can't modify the behavior of a parameter based on another parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps use [Conditions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html) and [Conditions Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html):

```
Parameters:
  MyParam:
    Default: false
    Type: String
    AllowedValues: [true, false]
Conditions:
  MyParamTrue: !Equals 
    - !Ref MyParam
    - true
```

Then inside resources:

```
Attribute: Fn::If: [MyParamTrue, [1,2,3], [1,2]]
```

Comment: He's asking specifically about parameters having dependencies on each other

Comment: Well,  the Fn::If array is not a parameter, but it does change dynamically, based on the parameter value.

Comment: Yeah, but that's for resources. You can't do that for parameters